# event по процентности состояние scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, прокрутка

Есть div(CanvasContainer)  в котором много канвас элементов.

```
<div id="DVTPslide" class="dd" style="display:block;"><canvas id="canvas01" height="1204" width="851"></canvas><canvas id="canvas11" height="1204" width="851"></canvas><canvas id="canvas21" height="1204" width="851"></canvas><canvas id="canvas31" height="1204" width="851"></canvas><canvas id="canvas41" height="1204" width="851"></canvas><canvas id="canvas51" height="1204" width="851"></canvas><canvas id="canvas61" height="1204" width="851"></canvas><canvas id="canvas71" height="1204" width="851"></canvas><canvas id="canvas81" height="1204" width="851"></canvas><canvas id="canvas91" height="1204" width="851"></canvas></div>
```

И по скролу у этого дива я должен удалить первые 5 элементов. Вроде сделал. Но мучает вопрос нельзя ли Scrolltop процентность состояние скрола выщитать. Пытался но без толку.

```
canvasContainer.onscroll = function() {
          /*  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
         var wh = document.getElementById('DVTPslide').offsetHeight;

// st : wh = X : 100
// x = (st*100)/wh

var perc = st/wh*100;
         */
         console.log(perc);
        if ($(this).scrollTop()>11000)
            {

            }
}
```

Comment: что значит _Scrolltop процентность состояние скрола выщитать_?

Answer (score 1):

```
canvasContainer.onscroll = function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    var wh = $(this).height();
    var perc = st/wh*100;
    console.log(perc);
}
```